# how to get the raw query for mysql in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In CodeIgniter using `last_query()` we get the raw query which we can use for testing in MySQL.

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

But in laravel what is the function or process to get the raw query.

Answer (score 1):

To get the raw query in Laravel you can use :

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

The most recent queries will be at the bottom of the array.

If this is turned off by default now. To use, you'll need to enable it manually using:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `tosql()` at end of Query

**Example**

```
$data = User::where('email', '=', $email)->tosql();

dd($data); // outputs raw sql on respective query
```